# Create arcs in CSS canvas and rotate towards the central circle

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I want to create `arcs` in `CSS` `canvas` and then want to rotate it for infinite time. There is a center div in round shape and I want `arcs` to rotate around that.

I tried to create a full image in the image editor (i.e. Paint) and then rotate it but I don't want to rotate all the layers together. (There are 3 layers of arcs; yellow, orange and red) Even I want to make center circle static. On the base of a trigger, innermost, middle one or outer most layer will rotate individually.

I have created a single arc using this function:

```
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(100, 75, 50, 0, 1 * Math.PI);
ctx.stroke();
```

I don't know how to set all the arcs around circular div and rotate towards it.

Here you can check my code and output in a snippet. I am good in `HTML` and `CSS` but new in `canvas` concepts. Even I can use `Javascript` or `JQuery` if it is required. How can I achieve this functionality? Will the solution be responsive?

```css
img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -60px 0 0 -60px;
  -webkit-animation: spin 8s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: spin 8s linear infinite;
  animation: spin 8s linear infinite;
}

@-moz-keyframes spin {
  100% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes spin {
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://s22.postimg.cc/51w6ynd4h/arcs-final.jpg">
</div>
```